# About the usage of "had" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, idioms

> Epistemologically speaking, it is facts about the relationship **had** with the trusted that determines the justification of trust, it is not the mere absence of defeating reasons. ([Source](https://www.academia.edu/27885834/On_Telling_and_Trusting))

It seems to me that the usage of the "had" in the above sentence is problematic or at least weird. I take "the relationship had with the trusted" to mean "the relationship that is held with the trusted" or "the relationship held with the trusted". But the usages of "had" instead of something like "held" sounds not right to me. Is it so? Is it an old style?

Comment: The link only goes to a preview of the book, not to the actual source text from which the context can be seen. Based purely on the sentence itself, it's not a good example of writing in general. Forgetting about **had** (you can simply remove *had* altogether rather than replace it with *that is held*), *the relationship with the trusted determines the justification of trust* leaves me feeling puzzled. (As does *the mere absence of defeating reasons*.) So, to me, there are more problematic things happening than just the use of **had**, which is something I find pretty mild in comparison.

Comment: "I drank coffee" or "I had coffee"? We abuse `had` all the time, so its usage in your sentence looks fine to me. The overall sentence appears unnecessarily complicated though.

Comment: This link http://www.academia.edu/27885834/On_Telling_and_Trusting looks like the complete manuscript. It's a paper published in *Mind, Vol. 116*.

Comment: @rsadhvika So who had what in my sentence ?